# Python 3.8.2: filedialog.askopenfilename and ttk.Entry confilct

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to read a list from excel file and put it in combobox, but the probleme when i execute the code below, it is impossible to fill the Entry with keyboard, i should use the combobox before or change the window and switch back to activate the Entry and fill it.

the code and the excel file are in the link below.

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Label Frame ')
screen_width = int(win.winfo_screenwidth()/2)
screen_height = int(win.winfo_screenheight()/2)
win.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}+0+0")

File_opned = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Please select excel file.',
                                    filetypes=[('excel File',['.xls', '.xlsx', '.xlsm', '.xltx','.xltm', '.xlam'])])
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel(File_opned, sheet_name='Scenes')
file_Excel_list = excel_data_df['Scenes'].tolist()

label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(win, text='Test Infos ', bd=3, padx=10, pady=10)
label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=40)


cur_label1 = ttk.Label(label_frame, text = 'What is your name : ')
cur_label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

cur_label2 = ttk.Label(label_frame, text = 'Scenes : ')
cur_label2.grid(row=1, column=0)


cur_entrybox = ttk.Entry(label_frame, width=19, textvariable=tk.StringVar())
cur_entrybox.grid(row=0, column=1)

cur_combobox = ttk.Combobox(label_frame, width=16, values=file_Excel_list)
cur_combobox.grid(row=1, column=1)

def submit():
    print(cur_entrybox.get())
    print(cur_combobox.get())

submit_btn = ttk.Button(win, text='Submit', command=submit)
submit_btn.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)

for child in label_frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=4, pady=4)

win.mainloop()
```

[excel file and source code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o_ckbvaRMjwNqKc_V5ypSS7uoI7eqQC5?usp=sharing)

Comment: even with focus the issue is not resolved. i recorded a video to show the problem in case you cant execute and try the code.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bSF08MIHAmkG5nSAjBXHYoYwTPtBX0ee/view?usp=sharing

Comment: video 2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s38Upm3aIh3UK-qD2MoAicfykLEywIbw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, remove `textvariable=tk.StringVar()` as it's useless.

Comment: Are you running windows? This looks like a known, longstanding bug. Try to rearrange your code to not open the file dialog until after mainloop starts to run and see if that rectifies the problem.

Comment: @stovfl thank you for your proposal, but the idea is to creat a frame with Entry and combobox dynamically, the the number of Entry and combobox is dynamic, it was my mistake i didn't share the full code. you can find he full code here [liveDemoFull](https://repl.it/repls/VirtuousStarryPoints#main.py)

Comment: @BryanOakley yes the Os is Windows 10, thank you for the tips, i think i can't rearrange the code (may be it is possible but not for beginner like me :( ). if you have any idea for rerrangement it will be great, the code is here [the full code](https://repl.it/repls/VirtuousStarryPoints#main.py)

Comment: @WLAS ***i think i can't rearrange the code***: My given Demo link shows how to do.

Comment: @stovfl, i tried without success to use the same logic as you for the dynamic case (my shared live) with multiple Combobix and Entry. i will try again and i hope that i can find a solution.

Comment: @stovfl yes thank you, it work great for the initial issue, i tried to use the same logic for the full code (shared live) without success.

Comment: I have upated your Live-Demo accordingly, see the new [Live-Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CulturedSufficientPasswords#main.py)

Comment: @stovfl You are great, it work perfect, thank you very much. exactly what i need